# UDP port scanner issues, C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port

So I am trying to create a functional udp port scanner. The code I have so far seems to be missing something such maybe switch, use of iwreq or simply a linked list for the scanned ports, not sure. I am new to C programming so would appreciate any help.

```
#include <erno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <iwlib.h>
#include <wireless.h>

#define MAXSIZE 0

int main(){

struct timeval timesec;
int sockfd;
int ipleng;

int port= 1020;
struct hostent hostent;
struct sockaddr my_addre;
struct imcmphdr IC;
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
struct ip ipp;
struct iw_range rang;
struct iwreq iwq;
char message="  ";
h_addr_list[0];



scan();
if(scan==NULL){
perror("scan not done");
exit(1);

}
int scan(){
ioctl(socket,SIOCSIWSCAN,&iwq);
iw_get_range_info(sockfd,wlan0,&rang);
  if(iw_get_range_info(sockfd, wlan0, &rang)>0){
    rang=1;
  }
   r=iw_get_range_info(sockfd,wlan0,&rang);
char serve [50];
int hlen;
int slen;
for(int i=0; port<r; i++){
if(hostt=getnameinfo(struct hostent  *host, MAXSIZE, host, hlen, serve, 
slen, NULL)==NULL){

if(haddrinfo=getaddrinfo(struct hostent *host, MAXSIZE, host, hlen, serve, 
slen, NULL)==NULL){
exit(1);
}
else{
printf("IP address");
addrlist=h_addr_list;
for(i=0; addrlist[i]>0; i++){
printf("host: %s\n", arrdlist[i],  hostt);
printf("server: %s\n", haddrinfo);

if(sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))<0 {
   perror("socket not created");
   return -1;

if(rsock=sockfd(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP))<0){
    perror("socket fail"); 
    exit(1);
    else{


memset(&my_addr,0,sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port=htons(1020);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr();
my_addr.sin_addr(struct in_addr*)hostt->h_addr;



if(sendto(sockfd,MAXSIZE,0,0,(struct sockaddr*)&my_addre,sizeof(my_addre))
<0){
    perror("can't send");
    return -1;
   }
  }
 }
}
if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&host,sizeof(host))== -1){
    perror("setsockopt(SOL_BROADCAST)");
    return -1;
    else
        timesec.tv_sec=3;
     while(1);
    {
    FD_ISSET(&my_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(&rsock,&readfds);
    ipleng=ip->ip_hl<<2;
    if(select(rsock+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&timsec);
    for(;;){
        if(select(rsock+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&timesec){
        if(FD_ISSET(rsock,&readfds0{
            siz=read(rsock,(struct icmphdr*)&IC,sizeof(IC));
            if(siz=0){
                printf("can't read");
            }

         }


        }
  } 
        ipp=(struct ip*)MAXSIZE;
        message=(struct icmp*)(MAXSIZE+ipleng);
        if(recvfrom(rsock,MAXSIZE,sizeof(MAXSIZE),NULL,my_addre,hlen)<0){
            perror("ICMP error");
            printf("port closed");
            if(message->icmp_type==ICMP_UNREACH)&&message->icmp_code==ICMP_UNREACH_PORT{
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                if(message==0){
                    printf("p;ort open");
                    port=getservbyport(htons(addrlist[i], "port");
                    printf("udp port %d %s is open\n", addrlist[i], port->s_addr);
                    if(port==NULL){
                        printf("unknown");
                    }




                }





            }


          }


        }
       }

      }

    }



  }




  }
 }


fflush(sockfd);
return 0;



}
```

Comment: It is missing proper formatting at the very least.

Comment: Please go to [help] and find out how to ask and what to ask about. You may have a [mcve] but there is no clear problem statement as well as no description of the problem.  IOW, a little effort on your part is required.

Comment: `if(select(rsock+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&timsec);` <<-- Seems nonsensical. And: in the loop below it, you have to reinitialise your FD_SET before every select(), , since select() modifies it.

Comment: You can avoid a lot of unreadable indentation by not using this kind of code structure: `exit(1);
}
else{` #codingstyle avoiding this: ` }
                }
            }
          }
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
  }
 }` at the end

Comment: There are many errors in your code as written.  I recommend you first try to format it in a C-ey way.  Then, start running the code through a compiler with warnings on.  On linux or mac, this would be "gcc -Wall filename.c". You'll get a lot of errors, but chip away at them!  Then, @Fabien's answer is a good starting point.  Good luck!

Comment: @wildplasser oh i thought select() might have been necessary :(

Comment: @EugeneSh yeah i hope that that will help things.

Comment: @Jeremy yeah it seems daunting to tackle these errors as im a newbie. but ill try.

Comment: @KevinDTimm the problem is there are several errors and not sure what is going on. I thought my code seemed similar to other udp scanners but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @cjj20 I'd start with a couple of things: indentation (!); In C, functions aren't defined inside other functions (like I think your scan() is); you misplaced your paren with `if(message->icmp_type==ICMP_UNREACH)&&message->icmp_code==ICMP_UNREACH_PORT{`;missing a paren in `if(select(rsock+1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&timesec){`;  Generally, I'd try to compile/check as you go, so errors don't build up.

Comment: @Jeremy ohh the function issue I will have to read up on how its done in C. And i will correct the errors you mentioned. I just hope I can make the code somehow resemble a scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thing like 'UDP port scanner' does not technically exist because UDP is stateless, so there is no connection.

Instead, what "UDP port scanners" do is send 'payloads' in order to try to get a response.

Basically a correct payload to test UDP 53 is a DNS request.

So you implement payloads, and you test all payloads on a port. Then you have a sort of UDP scanner.

Well I guess this does not answer your question but I hope it helps you perform a better scanner.

Comment: Thanks trying to get the code to send a packet to various ports and to detect which port respond with a icmp error but I will check out what you said.

Comment: On secured servers those ICMP packets are filtered while the expected UDP traffic won't be. That's why nmap will tell you `open|filtered` on those ports. Because he does not know if they are ICMP firewalled or open. Only a proper payload could tell. `nmap -sU -p 55555 8.8.8.8`

Comment: ok ill try that but the code seems so problematic (my code that is).